# Visual Studio, initterm not found, can't debug anymore

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to programming, i've been learning c++ on Visual Studio 2017 and so far haven't had any issues. Until now. I think at some point i misclicked on something, and now my Visual Studio is completely broken...

First of all running the programs does either nothing, or it executes the first few lines then nothing. Even on programs that worked perfectly when i previously tested them.

So in debug mode, things get weirder.

-When i try to set a breakpoint, i get a "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line."

-Additionally, stepping over things will pop up a window asking me to locate a initterm.cpp file which it apparently can't find anymore, suddenly. I looked that up and didn't get anything i could understand. Apparently it's an important file Visual Studio uses? I have no idea how it went missing all of a sudden.

Would greatly appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: _"When i try to set a breakpoint, i get a "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line."_: I suspect you trying to debug a release build if so this is normal. If not try an clean and full build.

Comment: I checked, but i'm in the debug build, and cleaning doesn't seem to solve anything. Still asks for that file. Might have to reinstall?

Comment: "initterm.cpp not found" isn't that bad. Microsoft ships a great deal of its own source code to help you debug some of the more complex problems. But normally you don't need that source code at all; you use Microsoft's already compiled versions.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Debugging->General

Make sure the code you are executing is the same as the one you are compiling.

If you missclicked one of the pop-ups of "failed compilation, want to run the old compiled code" and you click yes, ypu can go crazy.

Finally clean your solution Compiling->Clean solution